# <!doctype html> breaks 100% height

Tags: height, doctype

so I'm trying a simple experiment to get a fixed width column, and a fluid width one next to it.

It works fine with this code:
http://jsfiddle.net/qdWrH/

But when I add `<!doctype html>`
to it, suddendly it breaks. It's like the 100% height isnt accepted?

I've had a look around and can't quite find the right answer. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: were you able to solve the problem?

Comment: Here's a simple and clear explanation of the DOCTYPE issue:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/32215263/3597276

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
body, html {
    height:100%;
}
```

To allow div's to go to 100% height, their parents' (<body> and <html>) height needs to be set to 100%